# A recommendation for a good programming book in Threads and Concurrency in c\c++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, concurrency

HI all!

I'm currently taking the course Operating Systems in my university. We mainly study theory and have simple exercises in c++ to exercise some theoretical principles. 
I want to study more about the practical programming in concurrency and threads in c\c++ and i was wondering if any of you have a good book to recommend on.

Thank you all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also been looking for such a book, they are very hard to come by. This one will be released in May, if that's any help:

http://www.manning.com/williams/

I purchased this book:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0123705916/ref=oss_product

It's very good, it's in `java`, but most of the principles apply to `c`/`c++` anyway.

Answer (score 14):

1. Introduction to parallel computing: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/
2. POSIX threads programming: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 8):

If you will be working with UNIX-like systems, then I recommend [*Programming With POSIX Threads*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Threads-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201633922/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301839648&sr=1-1) by David R. Butenhof.

If you will be working with Microsoft Windows, then I recommend [*Writing Multithreaded Applications in Win32*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Writing-Multithreaded-Applications-Win32-Complete/dp/0201442345/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301839878&sr=1-1) by Jim Beveridge and Robert Wiener.

Irrespective of which threading package(s) you will end up using, I recommend you look at two presentations I wrote: [*Generic Synchronization Policies*](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/training-courses.html#training-gsp) and [*Multi-threaded Performance Pitfalls*](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/training-courses.html#training-multi-threaded). Those short presentations contain useful information that, unfortunately, is not discussed in many other books and articles.